# Specific Ruby on Rails routes deliema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, httparty, custom-routes

Currently developing a RoR mobile web application for displaying information about particular places.

Let's call these places 'installations'. Each installation has at least one 'venue', which is a specific instance of the installation. So for example an installation could be a city park, and one of its corresponding venues could be the park during a concert or event. If this example is confusing, disregard, it doesn't matter much.

The data for these installations and their corresponding venues is hosted on Amazon Web Service S3 as json objects. I use HTTParty to read in the AWS S3 json objects. I am currently reading them in like so:

In the application controller I have:

```
inlcude HTTParty
base_uri 's3.amazonaws.com/our_bucket'
before_filter :set_up_httparty

def set_up_httparty
  @installation = "INSTALLATION"
  @venue = "VENUE"
  @dir_url = "/#{@installation}/#{@venue}/"
end
```

In my corresponding controllers, where I get separate information I have:

```
response =
  ApplicationController.get("#{@dir_url}/ConstantUniqueName.json")
```

Currently I am hardcoding INSTALLATION and VENUE values to point to a specific set of folders. This works great, but I need to be able to take in these values from the url like so:

```
www.themobilewebapp.com/INSTALLATION/VENUE/index
```

Now I am sure it is most likely possibly to pass in these values with params like so:

```
www.themobilewebapp.com/index?installtion=INSTALLATION&venue=VENUE
```

But if possible I would like to set my URL's up the previous way. I need to have the URL's be friendly for users to put in themselves and have QRC codes point directly to a specific installation and corresponding venue.

If not possible to be able to do something like www.mobwebapp.com/INSTALL/VEN/index then is it possible to set up sub domains for each venue and then pull in that venue as a string?

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this in your `config/routes.rb` file then you will be able to use the URL pattern that you want:

```
match ':installation/:venue/index', :controller => :venue, :action => :index
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I want though. I don't have controllers for specific venues, I just want to be able to read the installation/venue in as data. So I want /:installtion/:venue/index to direct to just a completely separate controller and its action is index, and then I use the 'venue' data to read a specific file on AWS within that controller.

Comment: The above route is for a single controller that covers all installations and venues.  When `/INSTALLATION/VENUE/index` is requested, `VenuesController#index` is called with `params` set up with `installation` and `venue`.  You can then do your AWS lookup using the given params and deliver the result.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot. If it all works out then I apologize for dismissing it so quickly. :)

Comment: And look at that, it worked exactly like I wanted. Again sorry I doubted you. Thanks!